# How to extract "parent with two child's" pattern from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to extract all parents who has two child's from HTML

**Example 1**

```
<parent>
 <child>
  <tag></tag>
 </child>
 <child></child>
</parent>
```

**Example 2**

```
<parent>
 <parent_and_child>
  <tag></tag>
  <tag></tag>
 </parent_and_child>
 <child></child>
</parent>
```

Example 1 should output `<parent>` Example 2 should output `<parent>` and `<parent_and_child>`

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Oddly specific, did you try http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/ and https://api.jquery.com/length/ ?

Comment: @freedomn-m, I think he is looking for a pattern, not to apply logic on the array

Comment: Use recursion to traverse through the nodes and check if the number of children of the current node is 2. If so, perform the required actions.

Comment: @Exorcismus my bad, should have been https://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($){
        $('.common').each(function(){
          //If tag has 2 children get the name of node
            if ($(this).children().length == 2 ) {
               console.log($(this)[0].nodeName);

            }
        });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add the common class to each tag -->
<parent class = "common">
 <parent_and_child class = "common">
  <tag class = "common"></tag>
  <tag class = "common"></tag>
 </parent_and_child>
 <child class = "common"></child>
</parent>
```

Comment: No need to add class  `common` to *every single node* (overkill) - you can use `*` but it also picks up body/html so you just need a wrapper and specify that, eg `$(".container *")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://api.jquery.com/filter/ to find all the nodes that have 2 children, then https://api.jquery.com/map/ to get just the nodeName (if you didn't want actual DOM elements)

```js
var results = $("body *").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length == 2;
  })
  .map(function() { return this.nodeName; })
  .toArray();

console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<parent>
 <child>
  <tag></tag>
 </child>
 <child></child>
</parent>

<parent>
 <parent_and_child>
  <tag></tag>
  <tag></tag>
 </parent_and_child>
 <child></child>
</parent>
</body>
```